# Adding noise to dataframe to simulate experiment results

Tags: r, dataset, noise

I've got a dataframe containing fMRi data; responses per recording site (columns) for different images (rows).

Now I'd like to add noise in order to simulate real expected data from an experiment. Does it make sense to add noise to every field, or do it per column/row? I.e. would the noise be expected to be constant per image or per recording site, or be random for every datapoint?

If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I.e. would the noise be expected to be constant per image or per recording site, or be random for every datapoint?" Interesting questions. However, these are questions a statistician would ask someone with domain knowledge, not the other way around.

Comment: @Roland Makes sense! I was wondering though if there's some common expectation for occurence of noise in data like this.